# MPMoviePlayerController movie length

Tags: iphone, datetime, mpmovieplayercontroller, movie

The question is - **how to get the movie length from `MPMoviePlayerController` object?**

I need this to create a progress bar. I have the method `[myPlayer currentTime]` to move progress bar while movie is playing. And the `[myPlayer setCurrentTime: doubleVal]` to rewind the movie. But I can't use all this without information about movie length, or movie end time.

Also, maybe exists another player to use in iPhone, instead of `MPMoviePlayerController`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get an iphone MPMoviePlayer video's total time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214958/how-do-you-get-an-iphone-mpmovieplayer-videos-total-time)