# How do you get an iphone MPMoviePlayer video's total time?

Tags: iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, duration

I just want to figure out how to get a video's total time in seconds. Is there video metadata that loads or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**MPMoviePlayerController** has a property **duration** (iOS 3.2+):

> The duration of the movie, measured in seconds. (read-only)
>
> @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSTimeInterval duration
>
> If the duration of the movie is not known, the value in this property is 0.0. If the duration is subsequently determined, this property is updated and a **MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification** notification is posted.

Comment: Glad Apple is making these improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of the video in bytes using NSdata. After that calculate how many bytes for playing one second of video. And you can calculate the length of the video:)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply use the (NSTimeInterval)duration property to get the videos length??